# RNFirebase 'keepSynced' not working as expected

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

We are using the react-native-firebase in one of our applications in which we have more than one reference (reference_A, reference_B, reference_C) at the same level and we want to restrict one of those references (reference_C) from getting synced with the Firebase Real-time Database but not the others.

For this, as suggested at [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache) and [RNFirebase Documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/database/query), we have used the 'keepSynced' method as below:

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
..
..
..
database().ref('/reference_C').keepSynced(false);
```

Also, to persist the data for offline usage, we have used the 'setPersistenceEnabled' as below:

```
database().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

But, when observed at the Firebase console, the 'reference_C' is getting synced when the device is coming online which is not as expected.

Any help with this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keepSynced` doesn't work the way you expect.  It's not possible to completely stop synchronization of a particular node.  You use `keepSynced` to indicate that you *always* want to synchronize a *specific* node.  It's effectively the same as adding an empty listener to a node, so that changed in the database are synchronized with the client.

If you're seeing that `reference_C` is getting synchronized, that means you added a listener to it somewhere else in your code, or you have a listener at the root node of the database, which is effectively synchronizing everything all of the time.

Comment: I've read many answers about keepSynced but I still don't understand what is the purpose of it or what it is about. I think there should be examples of using it or not.